# Recent Comments time not updating

Tags: blocks, comments

I have a `recent comments` block; however, it does not auto-update the time of the comments: the time it shows is the age of the comment when I decided to include the block. The only way I can update it is to click `Edit View` and then clicking `Save`. This causes the recent comment's time to be correct for that brief moment in time only; but obviously as it still doesn't auto-update it is soon incorrect again. I must also re-iterate that refreshing the page does not cause it to update. Being new to Drupal I am not sure if this is standard behaviour; however, it would seem exceptionally odd if it was.

**Edit**: I gather it has something to do with using `Time Ago` rather than explicitly stating the date - obviously, the date it was created is fixed but `Time Ago` will increase every second. It would seem odd to offer a functionality like `Time Ago` if it did not update via some sort of median, e.g., Ajax, or at least as a minimum every time the page was refreshed. A fixed figure is absolutely pointless. Still holding out that I am missing some crucial bit of info.

Comment: Are you sure you're not caching the view or have some kind of other caching turned on in the frontend?

Comment: Possibly this was occurring. I downgraded from Drupal 8 to 7 due to far too many bugs being present - lo and behold this no longer occurs. Thanks